# How to drag and drop on Mat chip grid?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In angular material V15, the `<mat-chip-list>` has been replaced and I'm using `<mat-chip-grid>` with `<mat-chip-row>` alternatively. I would like to use the drag and drop on the `<mat-chip-grid>` but it doesn't seem to work. It was working correctly with `<mat-chip-list>` in previous version.

Did you find an alternative?